# Cannot run Cypress on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, cypress

I am trying to run Cypress on Ubuntu 18.04 and keep getting the same error. Has anyone else ran into problems running Cypress on Ubuntu 18.04?

Cypress 3.8.2
Ubuntu 18.04

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running ```./node_modules/cypress/bin/cypress open``` (where you have a cypress directory within a NodeJs project directory).  I am asking because a working installation started failing me yesterday, but running it that way does work for me.

Comment: Have you tried running ```cypress cache clear``` and then reinstalling Cypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed here:  [Cypress verify command failing #6184](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6184)

I tried the suggested work around and my problems went away.

```sh
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x800x24 &
export DISPLAY=:1
npx cypress verify
npx cypress run
```

In the gitter feed Gleb Bahmutov explained

> "It seems Ubuntu 18.04 XVFB has a weird behavior where it does not set
>   default screen, we have added explicit set in cypress-io/cypress#6184
>   but it has not yet been released."