# Heroku worker suddenly crashes, logs don't show any of my scripts. What happened?

Tags: heroku, flask, logging

I have a flask, gunicorn, postgresql project hosted on heroku and it suddenly failed. I can access the logs, but there is no script that I wrote, so I am confused. I haven't added anything between "working" and "not working" so I don't know where I can start.

The log can be found in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fFiLmMxC).
The last part is:

```
2020-02-06T21:09:02.748093+00:00 app[web.1]: from werkzeug.contrib.cache import FileSystemCache
2020-02-06T21:09:02.748100+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'
2020-02-06T21:09:02.748789+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-06 21:09:02 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
```

I tried to add werkzeug to the requirements.txt, but that did not help. Which would have been strange anyway, because it was working fine without the change in the requirement.

If you could help me reducing the requirements.txt, it would be greatly appreciated.

Original requirements.txt:

```
cs50
Flask
Flask-Session
requests
gunicorn
psycopg2-binary
openpyxl
```

New, working ones:

```
astroid==2.3.3
attrs==19.3.0
Authlib==0.13
autopep8==1.5
awscli==1.17.9
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
backports.shutil-which==3.5.2
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
botocore==1.14.9
bs4==0.0.1
cairocffi==1.1.0
CairoSVG==2.4.2
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
check50==3.0.10
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.1
compare50==1.1.2
cryptography==2.8
cs50==5.0.3
cssselect2==0.2.2
cycler==0.10.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
docutils==0.15.2
EditorConfig==0.12.2
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Session==0.3.1
help50==3.0.0
html5lib==1.0.1
icdiff==1.9.1
idna==2.8
ikp3db==1.4.1
intervaltree==2.1.0
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jellyfish==0.7.2
Jinja2==2.11.1
jmespath==0.9.4
jsbeautifier==1.10.3
kiwisolver==1.1.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
lib50==2.0.7
logger==1.4
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.3
mccabe==0.6.1
natsort==7.0.1
nltk==3.4.5
numpy==1.18.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
openpyxl==3.0.3
pandas==1.0.0
pexpect==4.8.0
Pillow==7.0.0
plotly==4.5.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pycparser==2.19
Pygments==2.5.2
pylint==2.4.4
pylint-django==2.0.13
pylint-flask==0.6
pylint-plugin-utils==0.6
pyparsing==2.4.6
PyPDF2==1.26.0
Pyphen==0.9.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-magic==0.4.15
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.2
render50==3.1.3
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
retrying==1.3.3
rsa==3.4.2
s3cmd==2.0.2
s3transfer==0.3.2
six==1.14.0
sortedcontainers==2.1.0
soupsieve==1.9.5
SQLAlchemy==1.3.13
sqlparse==0.3.0
style50==2.7.4
submit50==3.0.2
termcolor==1.1.0
tinycss2==1.0.2
tqdm==4.42.1
twython==3.7.0
typed-ast==1.4.1
urllib3==1.25.8
virtualenv==16.7.9
WeasyPrint==49
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.16.1
wrapt==1.11.2
gunicorn
```

Comment: Please provide `requiremets.txt`.

Comment: I can revert back to a working version. I changed the readme.md in github. Thats all I can see in the comparision.

Comment: But still, please provide `requirements.txt` for a completness matter.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the requirements. It's back in a usable state. I did the freeze thing in my IDE and now my requirements are ugly, but working. Got to figure out where the difference was.

Comment: I strongly recommend using `Poetry` for package managing.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it  @needtobe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Werkzeug released a new version yesterday :

[Release history](https://pypi.org/project/Werkzeug/#history)

Apparently `werkzeug.contrib` has been moved to a separate module

It is recommended to try

```py
./env/bin/pip install werkzeug==0.16.0
```

Comment: Ha! I think this is the reason. Good to know it was not directly my code. Or it was, but only because I did not specify the version. Thanks a lot, Martin.

Comment: Yeah.  That bug cost me about six hours of trying to figure out which change I had made that so seriously screwed the pooch.  And two weeks ago I lost 12 hours for this :: [Cannot run Cypress on Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59866937/1544075)  Is this going to be a trend now?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that might work for you.

Since that `Werkzeug 1.0.0` has removed deprecated code from `werkzeug.contrib`.

I ran into the same issue when trying to use `Proxyfix` in `werkzeug==1.0.0`

After downgrading to `werkzeug==0.16.0`, I got these warnings:

```
DeprecationWarning: 'werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix' has moved to 'werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix.ProxyFix'.
This import is deprecated as of version 0.15 and will be removed in 1.0.
DeprecationWarning: 'werkzeug.contrib.cache' is deprecated as of version 0.15 and will be removed in version 1.0. It has moved to pallets.
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import FileSystemCache
```

To fix the issues:

```
pip install werkzeug==1.0.0
```

For `ProxyFix`:

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
```

For `FileSystemCache`, you will have to install pallets:

```
pip install -U cachelib
from cachelib.file import FileSystemCache
```

I hope this helps and fix your issues

Comment: Thank you, that would be a solution if I need to use a newer version of werkzeug. So far I keep using the old version, as I don't need anything special from the new one. Who knows if that holds true for the future. Now I know how to handle that case.